# Error updating database record from a textbox

Tags: vb6

Good Day! I am trying to update the information on my database by using textboxes. I get the id of the record by this:

```
Dim dataID As String
dataID = lblID.Caption
rx.Open "SELECT * FROM tblclient WHERE ID = '& Trim$(dataID) &'", con, 3, 3
```

then I check if the record is available, but unfortunately, no matching record has been found even though there is an existing one. This is my first problem.

```
If rx.EOF Then
    MsgBox "No matching data"
Else
    MsgBox "There is a match"
End If
```

My second problem is, I cant update the information in the database, I'm using this line of code, I know i'm not doing this right, but I can't seem to find any solutions and I am really-really new in VB6.

```
With rx
 .Fields("Firstname") = txtFirstName.Text
.Fields("Lastname") = txtLastName.Text
 .Fields("District") = txtDistrict.Text
 .Fields("co_Maker") = txtCoMaker.Text
 .Fields("Address") = txtAddress.Text
 .Fields("Interest") = txtInterest.Text
 .Fields("ContactNo") = txtContactNo.Text
 .Update
End With
```

Please someone help me. 
I'm using VB6, MySQL database, ADO, and a datagrid.

Here is my overall code:

```
    Private Sub cmdSavetest_Click()
    Set Connect = New Class1
    Set rx = New adodb.Recordset

    Dim dataID As String

    dataID = lblID.Caption

    rx.Open "SELECT * FROM tblclient WHERE ID = '& Trim$(dataID) &'", con, 3, 3

    If rx.EOF Then
        MsgBox "No matching data"
    Else
         MsgBox "There is a match"
    End If

     With rx
      .Fields("Firstname") = txtFirstName.Text
      .Fields("Lastname") = txtLastName.Text
      .Fields("District") = txtDistrict.Text
      .Fields("co_Maker") = txtCoMaker.Text
      .Fields("Address") = txtAddress.Text
      .Fields("Interest") = txtInterest.Text
      .Fields("ContactNo") = txtContactNo.Text
      .Update
    End With

    rx.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SQL statement should probably be:

```
"SELECT * FROM tblclient WHERE ID = '" & Trim$(dataID) & "'"
```

giving you this line:

```
rx.Open "SELECT * FROM tblclient WHERE ID = '" & Trim$(dataID) & "'", con, 3, 3
```

When troubleshooting an SQL statement, you can make it into a string variable so you can make sure it looks good in the Immediate window (Ctrl-G in VB6 IDE):

```
Dim sSQLStatement As String
sSQLStatement = "SELECT * FROM tblclient WHERE ID = '" & Trim$(dataID) & "'"
rx.Open sSQLStatement, con, 3, 3
```

You can add a Breakpoint (press F9 on the line you want to break at) on the `rx.Open` line and check the value of `sSQLStatement` either by hovering your mouse over the `sSQLStatement` variable or by typing the following in the Immediate window:

```
? sSQLStatement
```

**As for your second problem**, I think you just need to add `.Value` to the `Fields` property:

```
With rx
    .Fields("Firstname").Value = txtFirstName.Text
    .Fields("Lastname").Value = txtLastName.Text
    .Fields("District").Value = txtDistrict.Text
    .Fields("co_Maker").Value = txtCoMaker.Text
    .Fields("Address").Value = txtAddress.Text
    .Fields("Interest").Value = txtInterest.Text
    .Fields("ContactNo").Value = txtContactNo.Text
    .Update
End With
```

Comment: Happy to help! Please mark the question as answered when you can.